# Integrate Facebook SDK inside my iOS Framework

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to integrate Facebook SDK inside my framework (which I publish to developers) but get a collision when users using my SDK already have Facebook SDK on their app. Is there any way around it?

Comment: I'd suggest you to port your framework to CocoaPods and add the Facebook SDK as a dependency to it, so it will not generate conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to only link Facebook SDK to your Custom Framework, but should not copy Facebook Framework inside your Custom Framework, you can also ship FacebookSDK.framework separately with your Custom Framework.

So there will be no collision between two FacebookSDK as the user will only add one FacebookSDK in their project. In this case users also aware of adding both two framework in their project.