# How to manage dependencies' conflicts between a framework that I'm making and the main app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, frameworks, dependencies

I'm making a framework (an SDK) that will be made public. I'm thinking about a situation when it's **not** distributed via Cocoapods / Carthage, but rather via a simple Downloads page.

In the SDK I need to provide users an opportunity to login and share via Facebook, so I would like to use appropriate Facebook SDKs (FBSDKLoginKit / ShareKit, I assume).  But if the end user of my SDK will also have these Facebook SDKs (or any other duplicate dependency), there will be a conflict.
What is the proper way to handle this situation without using Cocoapods / Carthage? I believe, one way is to avoid including / statically linking dependencies into my framework, but rather have end users download dependencies separately, but maybe there is another way around it? Making people download tons of libs from different sources isn't very convenient.

The question isn't about Facebook SDKs in particular, but about a general situation with third-party dependencies when developing a framework / library.

P.S. I found this question: [Integrate Facebook SDK inside my iOS Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16762553/integrate-facebook-sdk-inside-my-ios-framework). But it's specifically about Facebook, and it might be outdated (a lot of stuff happened in the iOS world since 2014).

**UPDATE:** the SDK will be closed source.

Comment: Which language are you using / targeting?

Comment: @Wain, sorry. Objective-C. I've added a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a combination of the two ideas you suggested:

Don't include the other SDKs directly in your framework, but have them in the same project when the user downloads it. That way, if the user doesn't already have them, they can copy over all of the frameworks that they need. And if the user does already have them, then they can just copy your SDK by itself and have it just work in their project.

This combination also allows you to include tests and samples in the download. Then users end up downloading a complete, functioning project that they can try out before integrating it with their own code.

Comment: Thanks, that would indeed be a way. Upvote to you. But I forgot one important detail (my bad, sorry): this will most likely be a closed source solution.

Comment: sorry, do you have a demo about this? I can not understand your ideas and how to. Thank you!